# Why do they call it alternating current (AC) not alternating voltage? The same goes for DC instead of DV (direct voltage.)

Tags: voltage, current, ac, dc

This takes me to my college studies 4 years ago. My teacher taught us that there is AC and DC electricity  alternating current and direct current respectively. I also drew a graph for voltage and current separately - current and voltage are different, it is basic knowledge. The teacher asked "Why is it called alternating current not alternating voltage? Both graphs are sine waveform." I started thinking why alternating current and why can't they be called alternating power because power equals to voltage * current, right?